# Default Values using Entity Framework 4

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, default-value, entity-framework-4.3

I have a table with a column as:

```
nvarchar(256) NoteInternal NOT NULL DF_ReOptions_NoteInternal DEFAULT ''
```

I'm using Database First approach and T4 for generating the POCOs. As I can see from my Model the Default Value for the property is not set.

A good explanation of why at this page
[Entity Framework 4 and Default Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586466/entity-framework-4-and-default-values)

When I'm setting manually the Default Value in the model I can see the default value in the POCO generated, but at the moment of saving on the database the default value is not being inserted and I receive an error in VS and not data in the DB.

My question, How can i insert default value using EF?

May I use DataAnnotation or System.ComponentModel namespace to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm using EF Database First approach and not Code first. So it is a different question I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: "As I can see from my Model the Default Value for the property is not set." Is it blank or does it say "<None>".

Comment: Yes the same for me, in my case adding a default value in the model does not save on the db... any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Smt I have tried and does not work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137738/how-to-set-default-value-for-pocos-in-ef-cf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here some of the possible solution for my case:

01 - Implementing some BL logic on DbContext overridding SaveChanges()

[EF 4.1 - How to add a default on insertion for datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237619/ef-4-1-how-to-add-a-default-on-insertion-for-datetime-column)
I chose this option

02 - Adding the default value in the View (using MVC)